# Propagate exception thrown from Continuation::resumeWith() back to the calling await()

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, coroutinescope

I have the following coroutine and corresponding Java wrapper:

```
suspend fun test() : String {
    delay(1000)
    return "OK"
}

@JvmOverloads
fun testWrapper(scope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)) : Deferred<String> =
        scope.async { 
    test() 
}
```

The following 2 test cases:

```
@Test
fun test1() = runBlocking {
    try {
        test()
        throw RuntimeException("TEST EXCEPTION")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Got the exception ", e) // We get the exception, all good
    }
    assertTrue(true)
}

@Test
fun test2() = runBlocking {
    try {
        testWrapper()
        throw RuntimeException("TEST EXCEPTION")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Got the exception ", e); // We get the exception, all good
    }
    assertTrue(true)
}
```

Test1: Calls `test()` and then in the "completion" throws an exception.
Test2: Same but calls the wrapper instead (`testWrapper()`)

In both cases the exception is caught and "Got the exception" is printed.

All good.

Now doing somewhat the same from Java:

```
@Test
public void testJava() {
    try {
        testWrapper().await(new Continuation<String>() {
            @NotNull
            @Override
            public CoroutineContext getContext() {
                return Dispatchers.getIO();
            }

            @Override
            public void resumeWith(@NotNull Object o) {
                Log.i(TAG, "IN CALLBACK");
                throw new RuntimeException("TEST EXCEPTION");
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Got the exception ", e);  // <---- NEVER CALLED
    }


    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

... results in the exception in the completion not getting to the exception handler with "Got the exception" log.

Instead looks like the generic unhandled exception handler is called and the app is terminated as a result.

My questions are:

- How do I propagate the exceptions from the `resumeWith()` going down to `await()` so I can catch them at the place where the call is made (similar to the Kotlin test)?
- Obviously I am missing something in my understanding. What exactly is happening here when called form Java?

This is the log from the last test (`testJava()`):

```
    AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
    AndroidRuntime: Process: com.x.test, PID: 18038
    AndroidRuntime: kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutinesInternalError: Fatal exception in coroutines machinery for AwaitContinuation(DispatchedContinuation[Dispatchers.IO, Continuation at kotlinx.coroutines.DeferredCoroutine.await$suspendImpl(Builders.common.kt:101)@2bf2e83]){Completed}@7e4e800. Please read KDoc to 'handleFatalException' method and report this incident to maintainers
    AndroidRuntime:     at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.handleFatalException(DispatchedTask.kt:144)
    AndroidRuntime:     at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:115)
    AndroidRuntime:     at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
    AndroidRuntime:     at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    AndroidRuntime:     at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
    AndroidRuntime:     at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
    AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: TEST EXCEPTION
    AndroidRuntime:     at com.x.tests.TestsJava$4.resumeWith(TestsJava.java:223)
    AndroidRuntime:     at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:46)
    AndroidRuntime:     at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    AndroidRuntime:     ... 4 more
```

Comment: Wait, but Kotlin and Java code aren't the same, are they? In Kotlin you don't care about the deferred, you don't await for it. In Java you do.

Comment: Also, even if you do await in Kotlin, these examples will be still different. Kotlin code can suspend, Java code can't. `await()` in Kotlin is synchronous, but this above `await()` example in Java is most probably asynchronous, so exception can't be caught.

Comment: Sorry I was trying with `.await()` and without in `test2()`. I forgot to put it in the code above ... but exact same thing/flow happens with test2() in both cases. The exception is caught in the catch.

Comment: Ah excellent point!! The Java `await()` is NOT synchronous!! .... hmmm Now I wonder how to properly call this coroutine from Java and properly handle the exception from the calling place when things go wrong...

Comment: You can't easily re-create Kotlin suspending code in Java. But what is your real case? Where does this exception originate from? Throwing an exception just to catch it in the same function does not make too much sense, so I guess in the real code either throwing or catching happens in another place.

Comment: Technically speaking suspending in Kotlin works in the way that it also only passes a continuation to `await()` (asynchronously), immediately exit from the try block and even from the `test1()` function. But then continuation invokes `test1()` again and jumps to the `throw` line directly. I think we can't simulate the same behavior with Java code, we would need gotos.

Comment: I have a suspend-able coroutine (test() in the example), used from all over the place in Kotlin and works great. However there is also Java legacy code ... so I am trying to wrap this coroutine (with the testWrapper() in the example) so I can properly call it from Java. The issue I am having, is error handling, then the coroutine (test()) fails, I need to properly catch the exception in Java at the right place instead of crashing the app (which is the default behavior now)

Comment: Looks like the code below can be used to write a latch wrapper in java:

Comment: public void javaTest2() {
        try {
            Deferred<String> deferred = testWrapper();
            deferred.invokeOnCompletion(throwable -> {
                if (throwable != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ERR:", throwable);
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "OK:" + deferred.getCompleted());
                }
                return Unit.INSTANCE;
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "E:", e);
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

Comment: Just return a `CompletableFuture` instead of `Deferred`. You can create it with `scope.future {}`. `CompletableFuture` is more native to Java, so it should be easier to use either by blocking or with callbacks and it will properly pass exceptions to the Java code.

Comment: Thank you! Returning CompletableFuture from scope.future {} looks much better!!! That should definitely fix my issue and expose this properly to Java land. I appreciate it. .... Basically answer to this question is: To properly expose a Kotlin coroutine to Java: Use scope.future to return a CompletableFuture. (any other method is problematic)